# correct usage of “moved up"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions

I am not a native speaker.

Is that appropriate to say:

> The assignment was discussed a while ago, that was before you **moved up**/promotion.

Is "move up" has a positive meaning, can I say:

> That was before you **moved up** to a coworker that just got promoted.

Answer (score 1):

***Moved up*** is a phrasal verb that can mean *promoted*. So you can use one or the other, but you should avoid using both.

So, your first sentence might read:

> The assignment was discussed a while ago, that was before you **were promoted**.

If you wanted to use *moved up* instead, you could say:

> The assignment was discussed a while ago, that was before you **moved up**.

I think “moved up” has a rather informal informal feel in that context, although you could rectify that by adding an object to the phrasal verb:

> The assignment was discussed a while ago, that was before you moved up **into your new position**.

If you don’t mind the informal feel, that could be changed to:

> The assignment was discussed a while ago, that was before you **moved up the company ladder**.

(A “company ladder” refers to the hierarchy of a work organization. People who are getting promotions to higher positions are said to be going *up the company ladder*.)

As for your second sentence, I’d recommend the same thing: avoid using *promoted* and *moved up* in the same sentence. In other words, change:

> That was before you moved up to a coworker that just got promoted.

to:

> That was before you moved up into your new position.

or:

> That was before you were promoted into your new position.

although you could use the noun form of *promote*, and keep this very brief:

> That was before your promotion.